# javaScript/HTML -Captions with bxslider

Tags: javascript, html, bxslider

I am using the bxslider as my template.
 i have to display in each picture a caption at the bottom of the picture.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
                    <pictures:each bean="${bean}" companyType="${companyType }" pictureList="${pictureList }">
                        <g:if test = "${picture.getLargeImageURL() != null && picture.getThumbnailImageURL() != null}">
                            <li>
                                    <img style="height: 240px; width: 100%"  src="${picture.getLargeImageURL()}" alt="${picture.copyright.copyrightify()}" title="${picture.caption.linkify()}"/>
                            </li>
                        </g:if>
                        <g:elseif test="${largeFileName != null && thumbnailFileName != null }">
                            <li>
                                    <img src="${resource(dir:'imgService',file:largeFileName)}" style="height: 240px; width: 100%" alt="${picture.copyright.copyrightify()}" title="${picture.caption.linkify()}"/>
                            </li>
                        </g:elseif>
                    </pictures:each>
                </ul>
```

How can I display the caption?

Comment: bxslider has very good documentation.. try going through them, its fairly simple

Comment: I have already found a solution.... look below

Answer (score 0):

http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

Just have to add the following attributes when the bxslider is called:

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode:'fade',
            captions: true
            });
```